# Exception while installing VFPOLEDB programmatically

Tags: c#, installation, oledb, visual-foxpro, failed-installation

I am trying to install VFPOLEDB driver via a console application.

I tried doing something like this

```
public void InstallVfpOledb()
{
            Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WindowsInstaller.Installer");
            try
            {
                Installer installer = (Installer)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                installer.InstallProduct(@"C:\VFPOLEDBSetup.msi");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write(e.ToString());
            }
}
```

So when I run the program I get the following exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005):
>   InstallProduct,PackagePath,PropertyValues    at
>   System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName,
>   BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData&
>   msgData)    at WindowsInstaller.Installer.InstallProduct(String
>   PackagePath, String PropertyValues)    at
>   installtest.Program.Main(String[] args) line 22

I believe `InstallProduct` method has path and property values as parameters.

I am missing those values I guess.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works for me:

```
// using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller in 
// Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll

try
{
    Installer.InstallProduct(@"C:\VFPOLEDBSetup.msi","");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.Write(e.Message);
}
```

It asks for permission if not run as administrator.

Comment: Thank you .This solves half of problem.
Now I have another error of VFPOLEDB not registered error.
For solving that problem I think I need to set some properties in here.

Comment: No. I think your problem is you are trying to use VFPOLEDB on a 64 bit compilation. Try targeting x86 in project properties. VFPOLEDB is 32 bits.

Comment: No I have x86 compilation.
I had installed VFPOLEDB normally and my application has been working smoothly for around 6 months.

Comment: Try installing the driver by selecting Just me option ,you will get the same error.

Comment: Both my VFP application (that too use VFPOLEDB) and C# applications are still running smoothly after I installed it with the above method.

Comment: BTW maybe I am evaluating it wrongly, try with , "ALLUSERS=1") in options parameter.

Comment: just in case if you know, is there any way by which I can add the oledb driver as prerequisite for my windows application?

Comment: Sorry  I am no good in setup projects, my coworker does all the setup things.